# Error running apt update on buggy xenial system

Tags: 16.04, apt

I have been running Ubuntu 16.04 on my older Dell (8yrs) now.  Recently things have been getting buggy.  Until 30min ago I could not `apt install` anything, I just resolved this issue by deleting 
    `/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages` and updating apt package manager.

First, and most important, when running 
    `sudo apt update`
I get the following error

```
`Err:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial Release 404 not found`
```

Other misc. craziness I am dealing with.

Symptom:  Occasionally (especially after running virtualbox for a while) my icons will disappear from the side bar, the text will disappear from the window bars, and the text will disappear from the gnome terminal window.

Comment: 404 means 'not found'  When I looked at http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/ I can see support for various releases including Trusty (14.04LTS) but not Xenial. When you added a PPA for a different release you should have expected issues.  No PPAs are included in 16.04 so you've added it.

Comment: So I deleted that ppa from Software & Updates and the problem is no more.  Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)